# Codeigniter ajax form validation error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have researched this code that will make my validation with ajax.

My controller is:

```
public function create(){


    $data = array('success' => false, 'messages' => array());

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('PROVINCE','Province Name','trim|required|max_length[30]|callback_if_exist');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="text-danger"','</p>');

    if($this->form_validation->run($this)){

        $data['success'] = true;
    }else{
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            # code...
            $data['messages']['key'] = form_error($key);
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

And my javascript is:

```
<script>
    $('#form-user').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var me = $(this);

        // perform ajax
        $.ajax({
            url: me.attr('action'),
            type: 'post',
            data: me.serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
                if (response.success == true){
                    alert('success');
                }else{
                    $.each(response.messages, function(key, value) {
                        var element = $('#' + key);

                        element.closest('div.form-group')
                        .removeClass('has-error')
                        .addClass(value.length > 0 ? 'has-error' : 'has-success')
                        .find('.text-danger')
                        .remove();

                        element.after(value)

                    });
                }
            }

        });


    });


</script>
```

At first my if else statement was:

```
            if (response.success == true){
                alert('success');
            }else{
               alert('failed');

                });
```

But when i put the codes:

```
  $.each(response.messages, function(key, value) {
                        var element = $('#' + key);

                    element.closest('div.form-group')
                    .removeClass('has-error')
                    .addClass(value.length > 0 ? 'has-error' : 'has-success')
                    .find('.text-danger')
                    .remove();

                    element.after(value)
```

The button doesn't work anymore if the validation fails.

Comment: *"The button doesn't work"* isn't a proper technical problem description. Inspect the actual response from server for clues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hard coding the string `'key'` in the php loop where you actually want the variable `$key`

Change

```
$data['messages']['key']
```

To

```
$data['messages'][$key]
```